# Mysqli $stmt->fetch returns false

Tags: php, mysql, exception, mysqli, fetch

I'm writing a website which requires me to allow users to create items with certain fields.  These users can then view the items, but the backend function which gets the item from the database is broken.  For some reason, the statement prepares and executes, but when I fetch the results, false is returned.  When I call $stmt->errno, the error number returned is 0.  Here is my code:

```
function item_get($mysqli, $iid) {
    if ($mysqli == null) throw new Exception('Could not connect to database.');
    if ($iid == null || $iid < 1) throw new Exception('Item id(iid) is required.');

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT i.iid, i.uid, i.name, i.price, i.condition, i.location, i.image_urls, i.description, i.category, i.subcategory, i.interval, i.deposit, i.terms_of_service, i.cancel_policy, i.min_rental_time, i.up_front, i.house_rules, i.room_type
        FROM items AS i WHERE i.iid = ?;');

    if (!$stmt)
        throw new Exception('Could not connect to database.');

    $iid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($iid);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $iid);

    $stmt->bind_result($item_iid, $uid_creator, $name, $price, $condition, $location, $image_urls, $description, $category, $subcategory, $interval, $deposit, $terms_of_service, $cancel_policy, $min_rental_time, $up_front, $house_rules, $room_type);

    if (!$stmt->execute())
        throw new Exception('Could not execute query.');

    if (!$stmt->fetch())
        throw new Exception('Could not execute query.');

    if ($item_iid == null)
        return null;

    $item = new Item($item_iid, $uid_creator, stripslashes($name), $price, stripslashes($description), stripslashes($location), $image_urls, $category, stripslashes($subcategory), $interval, stripslashes($condition), $deposit, stripslashes($terms_of_service), stripslashes($cancel_policy), stripslashes($min_rental_time), $up_front, stripslashes($house_rules), $room_type);
    return $item;
}
```

The second 'Could not execute query.' exception is thrown.  I tested it by adding random characters to the end of the second error message to distinguish it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  If I have not provided enough info, please let me know and I'll be happy to supply more.

Comment: Could this be just because I'm preparing my statement in a way that returns no results?  I just realized this thinking about how fetch() returns false when no results are remaining.

Comment: `fetch()` will return false if no rows are returned. That isn't an error state, so you should not throw an exception there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks much, I'll review my query!  I'm trying to finish something a coworker of mine started and quit before he finished, so his style is throwing me off.

Comment: No problem. This is a common mistake.  Your check for `$item_iid == null` should be sufficient.